# When answering the phone, do you say “this is it”?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, phrases

When you are answering the phone and being asked “Is this (your name)’s phone?”, do you say “Yes, this is it.”?
I feel this is unnatural but I am not so sure.

Comment: Presumably they really want to know who has answered the phone, so I would say "Yes, this is [name] speaking".

Comment: Agreed, although many people would just say **speaking**

Answer (score 1):

When you call somebody's personal number, you would expect that they would answer it personally. Let's say you're calling Jim on his personal number. You might say:

- Is this Jim? (some might say "is *that* Jim?")
- Am I speaking with Jim? (slightly more formal. Some might say "..speaking *to*..")

You wouldn't normally ask "is this Jim's phone" unless you had reason to believe it *wasn't* Jim who had answered. It sounds like you are confirming you've dialled the correct number rather than confirming who are you speaking to.

When *answering* a call, if someone asks "*is this Jim?*" Jim wouldn't respond "yes this is *it*" because Jim is a person, not an "it". If someone did ask "is this Jim's phone" (which would be a bit unusual for the reasons stated above) it would seem silly for Jim to simply say 'yes' to confirm they have the number right when he can just confirm "yes, this is Jim speaking".

Many people answer the phone by saying their name, or the name of their business followed by their own name. If answering somebody else's phone (eg answering a colleague's phone in their absence) some might say, for example, "Jim's phone" to denote that this is Jim's number, but not Jim speaking.